# Is there a way to set ignore case in .ackrc file

Tags: ack

I want to ignore case by default without having to specify "-i" option everytime I run "ack" command. Is there a way to do it in .ackrc file?

Answer (score 3):

Have this line in .ackrc file,

> --ignore-case

Comment: I like `--smart-case` which ignore case unless there are uppercase letters in the pattern.